# jquery $this problem

Tags: jquery

see this code

```
$(function() {
    $('.do').deleteTable({
        parent: $(".do").parentsUntil("#did")

    });
});
```

its works
but if i make it

```
$(function() {
$('.do').deleteTable({
parent: $(this).parentsUntil("#did")
});
});
```

not works; why?
i replace $(".do") to $(this)

Comment: ...you don't need to wrap this in $().

Answer (score 4):

`{ parent: $(this).parentsUntil("#did") }` is an object literal, calculated before it is passed to `deleteTable`.

It is not a `function` called back from `deleteTable` with `this` set to each element with class `do`.

So `this` is the outer `function() { ... }`'s `this`: namely `window`.

Answer (score 2):

This may help...

['this' demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)

Answer (score 1):

"this" is probably the "window" object, which won't have parents.

I'm guessing you're thinking of a situation as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('.do').click(function() {
    alert($(this).is('.do'));
    });
});
```

In the above case, when the function is run because of a click event, then "this" will be the $('.do') object you expect it to be.  In your case however, the context of "this" is not $('.do')

Answer (score 1):

When I'm in a similar situation, the first thing I do is set up a breakpoint and check (using firebug for example) if the $(this) is really what I'm expecting.

99% of the time that helps me understand what's going on.